# Button should be active in specific date range

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

`enter code here`

```
            <tr><td width="25%">Name:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td></tr>                       
            <tr><td width="25%">HQ:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['hq']; ?></td></tr> 
            <tr><td width="25%">Month:</td>
            <td><select name="month">
                    <option>select</option>
                    <option>Jan</option>
                    <option>Feb</option>
                    <option>March</option>
                    <option>April</option>
                    <option>May</option>
                    <option>June</option>
                    <option>July</option>
                    <option>Aug</option>
                    <option>Sept</option>
                    <option>Oct</option>
                    <option>Nov</option>
                    <option>Dec</option>                        
                    </select> </td></tr>
          <tr><td>Date :</td>
         <td><input name="date" class="date demo_vista" type="text"  id="" size="30" maxlength="50" />
            <div id="debug"></div></td></tr>
            <tr><td width="25%">Day:</td>
            <td><select name="day">
                    <option >select</option>
                    <option >Monday</option>
                    <option >Tuesday</option>
                    <option >Wednesday</option>
                    <option >Thursday</option>
                    <option >Friday</option>
                    <option >Saturday</option>                    
                    </select></td></tr>
            <tr><td>From:</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="frm" id="" size="24" /></td></tr>   
            <tr><td width="25%">To:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="to" id="" size="30" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Bus/Bike/Train:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="vai" id="" size="30" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Fare:</td>
            <td> <input type="textarea" name="fare" id="" size="30" /></td></tr>  
            <tr><td>Daily-A:</td>
            <td> <input type="textarea" name="daily" id="" size="30" /></td></tr>                           
            <tr><td>Other:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="other" id="" size="30" /></td></tr>
            <!--<tr><td>Total:</td>
            <td><?php echo $tot; ?></td></tr>-->

           <tr><td align="right"><input type="submit" name="add" class="submitbtn" value="Add" /></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input type="reset" value="Clear" class="submitbtn" /></td></tr>
            </table>
   </form>
   </div>

   <div align="center"><input type="button" value="Total Bill" class="submitbtn"  onClick="parent.location='total_bill.php'"/> </div>
enter code here
```

** how i can code for Last Button Should be Active on 27th to 1st date of every month..**

Comment: Add your code, what you did or try for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in php with below code

```
<?php
        $today = gmdate('d');
?>
<input type="Button" <?php if($today < 27 && $today != 1) echo 'disabled';?> name="buttonName" />
```

Comment: above code is not working.. from where 'd' get??

Comment: d is date, please paste your code, what you tried?